# If I have a 2x2 matrix ODE with 2 complex eigenpairs, am I able to write out 4 real solutions?

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

I am taking my first course in ODE and I have some confusion in solving 2x2 linear systems when the eigenpairs are complex. From my notes I see that I can write out 2 real solutions (real and imaginary parts of an eigenpair), does that mean if I have 2 complex eigenpairs, I can write out a total of 4 solutions?

I just realized that I was not able to characterize my question very well. But basically I have the equation $X'=AX$ where $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 &  \\
-1 & 0  \\ 
\end{pmatrix}$$

Then I solved for its two eigenpairs $(\lambda_1, \vec{v_1})=(\frac{1+i\sqrt3}{2}, (\frac{-1-i\sqrt3}{2}, 1)^T)$ and $(\lambda_2, \vec{v_2})=(\frac{1-i\sqrt3}{2}, (\frac{-1+i\sqrt3}{2}, 1)^T)$, but then I am not sure how to proceed from there.

My next step is to write out:

$$\vec{v_1}=(\frac{-1}{2}, 1)^T + i(\frac{-\sqrt3}{2}, 0)^T$$
$$\vec{v_2}=(\frac{1}{2}, 1)^T + i (\frac{-\sqrt{3}}{2}, 0)^T$$

and then ($\alpha_1, \alpha_2$ constants):

$$X=\alpha_1 e^{{\lambda_1}t} \vec{v_1}+\alpha_2e^{{\lambda_2}t} \vec{v_2}$$

and then apply Euler's formula to both parts but then I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: You can only get two _linearly independent_ solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x_1=e^{1/2t}e^{i\sqrt 3 /2 t}\pmatrix { -\frac 12  -i\frac {\sqrt 3 }{2} \\ 1}$$
Apply Euler's formula:
$$x_1=e^{1/2t}\left ( \cos (\sqrt 3 /2 t)+i \sin  (\sqrt 3 /2 t)\right)\pmatrix { -\frac 12  -i\frac {\sqrt 3 }{2} \\ 1}$$
Rearrange terms in the form $u(t)+iv(t)$:
$$x_1=e^{\frac t 2}\left ( \pmatrix { -\frac 12 \cos (\sqrt 3 /2 t) +\sin  (\sqrt 3 /2 t)\frac {\sqrt 3 }{2} \\ \cos (\sqrt 3 /2  t)}+i\pmatrix { -\frac 12 \sin  (\sqrt 3 /2 t) -\cos (\sqrt 3 /2 t)\frac {\sqrt 3 }{2} \\ \sin  (\sqrt 3 /2 t)}\right )$$
And the general solution of the system is:
$$x(t)=c_1e^{\frac t 2} \pmatrix { -\frac 12 \cos (\frac {\sqrt 3 }{2}  t) +\frac {\sqrt 3 }{2} \sin  (\frac {\sqrt 3 }{2} t)\\ \cos (\frac {\sqrt 3 }{2} t)} + c_2e^{\frac t 2} \pmatrix { -\frac 12 \sin  (\frac {\sqrt 3 }{2}  t) -\frac {\sqrt 3 }{2} \cos (\frac {\sqrt 3 }{2} t)\\ \sin  (\frac {\sqrt 3 }{2}  t)}$$

Comment: Thank you for this. Did you perhaps missed some "$t$'s" in the sin and cos functions?

Comment: Yes still correcting thanks @CharlieCornell

Comment: You have only txo real solutions. @CharlieCornell